# 16 bit (565) image read

Tags: java, image, graphics, bufferedimage, raster

I'm reading an image byte array now the image is 16 bit (r: 5, g: 6, b: 5) and I would like to read it to BufferedImage.

I have tried something like:

```
int[] nBits = {5, 6, 5};
int[] bOffs = {0, 0, 0};
ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(
        cs, nBits, false, false,
        Transparency.OPAQUE,
        DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
WritableRaster raster = Raster.createInterleavedRaster(
        new DataBufferByte(screenBuffer,screenBuffer.length),
        foundWidth, foundHight,
        foundWidth * 2, 2,bOffs, null);

BufferedImage imgReconstructed = new BufferedImage(
        colorModel,raster,false,null);
```

My issue is with the bandOffsets, how should I set it for 16 bit image. Is it the right way?
Thanks,
Guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createInterleavedRaster` method would be used to create an image with a sample model where each data element contained color information for a single band (i.e. red, green, or blue). If you want an image where each 16-bit data element contains all 3 color bands, you want to use one of the **`createPackedRaster`** methods instead.

The only sixteen bit data type supported by these models is unsigned short, so you will want to pass a `DataBufferUShort` instance.

I do not have access to a compiler at the moment to put together a working code sample for you, but the [SinglePixelPackedSampleModel](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/api/java/awt/image/SinglePixelPackedSampleModel.html) API documentation will help explain the scanlineStride and band mask parameters a little bit. If needed, I will update this response later with more details.